# Vue(x) NOT reactive when using Vue.set(...) but IS reactive when using Object.assign why?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm busy creating a simple environment monitor using Vue, Vuex and ZircleUI.
When using the following Vuex store mutation:

```
    updateDbArea(state, payload) {
        var dbArea = payload.data

        // NOT Reactive triggering the view's computed property!
        Vue.set(state.dbAreas, dbArea.key, dbArea);

        // Is triggering the View's computed property!
        state.dbAreas[dbArea.key] = Object.assign({}, state.dbAreas[dbArea.key]);
    },
```

With the following computed property:

```
    actualStatusClass: function () {
        return 'actual_status_' + this.$store.state.dbAreas[this.dbAreaKey].actual;
    },
```

The Vue.set(...) is NOT reactive but the Object.assign(...) is. I don't get why. Which one I'm miss using?

The page [Vue Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) doesn't explain this to me or I don't see it.

Kind regards,
Henry

Comment: Is it possible that `payload.data` is the same object that is already assigned to `state.dbAreas[dbArea.key]`? In the Object.assign example, you are assigning a different value.

Comment: @RoyJ No the ..actual property is 'OK', 'WARNING', or 'ALERT' and I'm using it for both Vue.set and Object.assign with the same values.

Comment: Arh you mean the reference variabele? That could be the case.

Comment: But then why doesnt Vue.set change the ref?

Comment: Try using Vue.set twice: once to set the value to `null`, then again to set it to whatever value you intend. See if there is a reactive response.

Comment: I do not have enough info to make an example, but Roy could be right, the set only set once, so it does not trigger computed. Try to set again with different data.

Comment: Roy is right Vue.set(..., {}) before the "real" Vue.set is triggering also. Thanks guys